# Python to stop stream when reaches end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to stream a list using yield. But the thing is my console keeps on printing even when I have reached end of the list. Basically it keeps on repeating. For example:

```
def auee():
    listabc = [1,2,3,4,5]
    def events():
        for i in listabc:
            print(i)
            yield "data: %s\n\n" % (i)


    return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

It should have ended after printing `1 2 3 4 5` . But the function keeps repeating itself and it keeps on printing:

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

...

Is this the usual behavior for yield. If yes, How can I stop this.

Comment: When I test-run this, it does end after printing all 5 elements. Notice, that events returns iterator object, so I'd look for the issue in the behaviour of Response function :)

Comment: @KrzysztofJurkiewicz yes I also feel the issue is in how Response function is implemented in Flask

Comment: I was going to post an answer to the question you just asked, did you figure it out already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479663/split-and-push-my-event-source-data-to-array

Comment: Yes, I made some changes on my server side instead of client side thanks for the help. Btw I would love to hear your approach